# AWS Load Balancer - Assets Uploads

Tags: craft3, assets, assets-field, aws, load-balancer

We have two ec2 instances and a private IP db instance along with a Amazon Load Balancer.

Is there a way to upload images on CraftCMS domain pointing to a load balancer?

Right now the assets image upload hangs.

The images are uploaded successfully if we disable the load balancer or when we create multiple A records pointing to the IPs resolved by querying the load balancer.

Is there a plugin or an effective way to resolve this?

Comment: "Right now the assets image upload hangs." - I'd check logs - either the ALB logs in Cloudwatch, wherever Craft's logs are configured to write to (in case the request is actually making it to the server), etc. and look for the underlying error to figure out where to debug.

Comment: I figured that the loadbalancer is causing the issue. When you point several A records to the IPs which the loadbalancer is resolving and removing the CNAME record, it works. This is not ideal when a load balancer is in place.